# Do POST-Parameters cause problems in the body (HTTP)?

Tags: http, parsing, url, post, parameters

I have researched a lot about this topic, but still have one question. Is it valid to POST to a URL like this:

```
POST /muster.html?Name=Max+Mustermann&Ort=Musterstadt&PLZ=1234 HTTP/1.1?
```

I've heard that the query-parameters are sent in the body. Does that cause any problems if there already is content in the body (say another string)? How are the parameters and the actual content separated by the "parser"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has a best possible answers for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request

Comment: Thanks...Do I get it right when I say that is is possible to POST to a URL containing a query string? Who defines where the query string is beings send (URL or Body): The browser?

Comment: Yes, its possible to POST to a URL containing query string. It can be any client (browser, postman, your code)

Comment: And I assume that once you receive the URL from a POST (with query-params) the server just has to parse it to get them....If that's right, I got it! Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are spot on!